# I want to render the number of images and images should be shuffle in react native? how to do that? Can any one help me

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface

Images should be shuffle when i'll click on that particular image in react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shuffle of lodash library or can make your shuffle function. 
I am taking image URLs as a number in the below example.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

// Used like so
var arr = [2, 11, 37, 42];
arr = shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Reference: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)